# need a fluentd sample to collect data from a url and send it to a rabbitmq container

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, prometheus, fluentd, rabbitmq-exchange

Im new to fluentd, im having a fluentd container with `fluent.conf`

```
<source>
  @type http
  port 9090
  bind my-ip-addr
  tag api
</source>

<match api>
  @type rabbitmq
  host rabbitmq
  port 5672
  user guest
  password guest
  vhost /
  exchange testlogexch
  exchange_type topic
  exchange_durable true
  routing_key testlogkey
  heartbeat 60
</match>
```

Im trying to get json data from prometheus url and I want it to be pushed to rabbitmq.

I tried for an example/sample to collect json data from a url and send it to rabbitmq,
but the urls what I saw in the documentation is simple and what I need is to collect data from a `uri` like this `/api/v1/query?query=cadvisor_version_info&time=1667589170.648`